d-dimensional random walk: scaling of probability of self-crossing
I have a random walk in $d$ dimensions. I want to know how the probability of a path crossing itself scales with the number of steps $N$. An exact solution is not needed.
I don't know how to solve this problem. I know that the probability distribution for the end-to-end distance $\vec{R}$ is a Gaussian, but I don't see how I can get the probability of self-crossing from that. Can someone help me with this problem?

Well, on every step of a random walk, it can go backwards and cross itself immediately, so the probability of not crossing itself decays at least as $\left(1-\frac1{2d}\right)^N$.
